# How to use DWD R package in order to remove biases and merge two microarray datasets

Tags: r, distance, weighted, genetics

I am trying to find a way to use distance weighted discrimination method (DWD) to remove biases from multiple microarray datasets.

My starting point is [this](https://genome.unc.edu/pubsup/dwd/). The problem is that Matlab version runs only under Windows, needs excel 5 format as input (where data appears to be truncated at line 65535 - matlab error is:

```
Error reading record for cells starting at column 65535.  Try saving as Excel 98.
```

). Java version runs only with caBIG support, which, if I understood, has been shut down recently.

So I searched a lot and I find [R/DWD](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DWD/DWD.pdf) package but from example I could not get how to provide the two datasets to merge to `kdwd` function.

Does anybody know how to use it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it has a DWD implementation
http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/inSilicoMerging.html